How best would you flatten a surface without distorting?
I'm looking to take an existing shape and represent it as closely as I possibly can in a flat 2D space so that it can be used as a template for a vinyl graphic design.
I have a model of the rear doors for a vehicle, from which I have managed to extract just the recess panels (see below)

As you can see, it is almost flat, but not enough. If I just scale X 0, it will distort it and give me a distorted shape that will be too small if used as the cutting edge for vinyl graphics.
What I need is for every edge to not lose its length in the process as it would if it were flattened as per the above method. I need a 2D shape that, if laid on the vehicle, would perfectly fit into that panel. Vinyl has some flexibility, but the closer we can get, the better.
Short of laying this shape onto a flat plane and manually rotating each vertex pivoted from the previous one such that each one sits on the plane (as if I'd took a rolled up or contorted piece of paper and unrolled it on a counter), I'm drawing a blank here. Any ideas? Thanks.
NB. Due to copyright agreements, I am not able to share the .blend file. There's nothing special about it, though. Feel free to use a similar mesh to demonstrate a potential solution.

Is the overall shape curved or just a bit slanted but straight? If curved, just from bottom to top or from front to back as well, it's not fully clear from the screenshot? If you do not have to do this over and over again so automation is required, the easiest and quickest would be to rotate everything to compensate for the slant to get it basically aligned with the world's axes and then flatten it on X. Not perfect, but I've done hundreds of vehicle labels for recess areas and all the labeling company needed was that it covered the area and they did the perfect fit directly on the vehicle.

@GordonBrinkmann it is curved on both axes basically, and in a non-uniform way. The way we tend to do these things is to use tracing paper on an actual vehicle and then produce the graphics to a perfect fit because the alternative is producing oversize and trimming on the vehicle but this is risky.

If it is curved on both axes, you will never get it straightened by rotating vertices without distortion, because curving on perpendicular axes would result in splitting the faces up if they do not get distorted.

Noted, and reasonable. Do you have a suggestion for how to achieve minimal stretch? Having it split and spoke out like peeled orange skin may work in some cases as a UV map but isn't something we can produce graphics to in the real world.

Is it not like UV unwrap ?

What about a cloth simulation, inspired by Martynas Žiemys comment : "If you have stretchy material, how it stretches depends on its physical properties and how it's stretched." ?

UV unwrapping deals with precisely the issue you have - it tries to minimize stretching as much as possible. So you could use UV unwrapping and all its functionality regarding minimizing stretching(like Minimize Stretch in UV menu in the UV Editor). You can also convert the UV map to mesh in various ways like with a script, or using Geometry Nodes or with add-ons. Not sure how many or which add-ons can do that, but one example would be TexTools:

You will obviously have problems with scale, because if the UV map is stretched it's sort of hard to define what the scale of it should be in relation to the model in 3d (should it only stretch, should it contract as well?..) so you have to figure out what works for you in terms of scale in real world and some sort of workflow to deal with it, but I really don't see better alternatives to this(this is probably way better than nothing).

Thanks. I had so far written off UV unwrapping as a solution for a few reasons including the requirement for seams as well as the drawbacks you mentioned. It's possible that this could work as a starting point, however. It's possible that what I need in terms of accuracy just isn't attainable to the degree required for my intended purpose.

The problem is physical. If you have stretchy material, how it stretches depends on its physical properties and how it's stretched. There is certainly no functionality for that in any 3d modelling software designed for CG. This is as good as it gets without the possibility to take physical properties and the exact physical process of applying it into account. "I need a 2D shape that, if laid on the vehicle, would perfectly fit into that panel." - that's wrong premise as the shape is 3D after stretching. The fit depends on how you stretch the material not only its initial shape.
